# force carbonating a scotch heavy ale

Tags: kegging, carbonation, techniques

I am brewing a scotch ale currently and haven't been able to determine how many volumes of co2 that it should have?  also,  what pressure should I put the beer under to carbonate to that many volumes.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you mean Scottish Heavy 70/- or Strong Scotch ale, but start around 2 volumes and go from there.

The amount of pressure depends on what temperature the beer is in the kegerator.  Cold beer will hold more carbonation at a given pressure than warm beer.  You need to consult a carbonation table like this one: http://brewery.org/library/CO2charts.html

Hope that helps